# /usr/lib and Conda Environments

Tags: python, python3, libraries, anaconda

I am trying to understand the proper way to go about solving an issue.

Background: I have Anaconda installed with the default python 3.7.7

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I am trying to run a program with python 3.6.8. So I made a conda environment and installed python 3.6.8.

The problem runs that in their install instructions they require making links in /usr/lib for instance like below:

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.so /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so
```

This doesn't seem like the best way to do so, though because it breaks the encapsulation of a conda environment.

What is the correct way to add libraries so that they work correctly with a conda environment?

Edit:

A comment below led me to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only

Which seems a better solution than linking the library manually.

Comment: That does seem weirdly contrary to the entire point of running conda. Perhaps you don't have your lib PATH ENV exported properly?? Perhaps this might point you in a useful direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298681/anaconda-python-virtualdev-cant-find-libpython3-5m-so-1-0-on-windows-subsystem Can you install `libpython3.6-dev` in the conda env?

Comment: That comment actually helped a ton. It is a much better solution than linking manually. It led me to this answer which seems ideal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only
This way I can set and unset the environment variables when activating and deactivating environments.

Comment: I wonder, though, why conda doesn't do this automatically for the environment lib folder.

Comment: Which version of Linux and which release number is in use? Different releases have different tools. Please click [edit] and add that to your question; please do not use Add Comment as that's our one-way channel to you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to setup a conda environment with a specific version of python, using python provided by conda, rather than trying to install or use a version of python provided by your operating system (Ubuntu).

```
conda create --name yourenvironmentname python=3.6.8
conda active yourenvironmentname
```

Then you should be able to run your program.

For further reading, consult the official documentation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python

Comment: This isn't helpful. I stated in my question:  So I made a conda environment and installed python 3.6.8.